# Attempting to automatically have an image change depending on the date

Tags: javascript, html, image, jsfiddle

The website I am working on is for taking football bookings, but I have a section on the website that features upcoming fixtures, and to cut out somebody having to change the code after every game I wanted to implement a fixture image that automatically changes depending on the date I.E so that it changes itself after the date of the match.

I have played around and I cannot see what I am missing... here is what I did:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLffJ/180/

```
I expect this to be stoke.

<img id="fix1" src="http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/chels.png" alt="Fixture1" width="75%" onload="fix1(this)" />

function fix1(img) {
if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
var d = new Date();
var Today = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth();
if ((Month === 8 && Today >= 1) || (Month === 9 && Today <= 13)) {
"http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/stokefix.png";
} else if ((Month === 9 && Today >= 14) || (Month === 9 && Today <= 27)) {
"http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/cpalfix.png";
} else if ((Month === 9 && Today >= 28) || (Month === 10 && Today <= 18)) {
"http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/newc.png";
} 
alert(src);
img.src=src;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you're not setting src in your if {} else.. statements

Comment: @CharlesA OP is setting `src` at end of function. OP: `if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return;` will stop your function from working because there is no `default` in your image source. And you should rename your function, it has the same name as your image `id`.

Comment: sorry - let me be more clear. In the if () {} statement, the line `"http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/stokefix.png";` doesn't do anything - you're not assigning the string to a variable

Comment: lines like this `"http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/stokefix.png";` should be changed to src = `"http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/stokefix.png";`

Comment: I'm curios how does `if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return;` detect that image is already changed..? i don't see `default` anywhere..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
function fix1(img) {
    //if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
    var d = new Date();
   var Today = d.getDate();
   var Month = d.getMonth();
   var src;
   if ((Month == 8 && Today >= 1) || (Month == 9 && Today <= 13)) {
       src = "http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/stokefix.png";
   } else if ((Month == 9 && Today >= 14) || (Month == 9 && Today <= 27)) {
       src = "http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/cpalfix.png";
   } else if ((Month == 9 && Today >= 28) || (Month == 10 && Today <= 18)) {
       src = "http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/newc.png";
   } 
   else {
       src = 'not defined';
   }
   alert(src);
   img.src=src;
}
```

btw, remember that getMonth returns months from 0-11 not 1-12 so you may need to change your 8 to a 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following updated image tag and JavaScript function. I commented first line in function and change ID

```
<img id="fix11" src="http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/chels.png" alt="Fixture1" width="75%" onload="fix1(this)" />

function fix1(img) {
 // if (img.src.indexOf('default')==-1) return; // already changed 
 var d = new Date();
 var Today = d.getDate();
 var Month = d.getMonth();
 var src ="" ;
 if ((Month === 7 && Today >= 1) || (Month === 9 && Today <= 13)) {
   src="http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/stokefix.png";
 } 
 else if ((Month === 9 && Today >= 14) || (Month === 9 && Today <= 27)) {
   src="http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/cpalfix.png";
 } else if ((Month === 9 && Today >= 28) || (Month === 10 && Today <= 18)) {
  src=  "http://www.ausdenclarkbookings.co.uk/image/newc.png";
 } 
 alert(src);
img.src=src;
}
```